# Is there a way to have an invisible scrollbar that works across most, if not all browsers?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In a bootstrap site I'm working on it has two columns which I made extend to the height of the viewport, and then any overflow gets handled with a scrollbar. That way the columns can just be scrollable instead of changing the height of the page.

The problem is that the scrollbars look really ugly, especially when there's so many. Is there a way to make the scrollbar invisible while keeping the column scrollable? I know there's some CSS but it doesn't appear to be compatible with all browsers so I was wondering if there was a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) here you have a lot of options for your scrollbar.